# C++ - Wrapper classes over implementation class

Tags: c++, struct, wrapper

I am trying to implement 2 wrapper class (1 user, 1 programmer) over some complete implementation.h file. My goal is for the user to NOT be able to access the struct or implementation details about the struct. The idea is also to only extend the necessary methods from implementation.h to either user/programmer. Any ideas?

implementation.h

```
class implementation{
    public:
        /*....methods.....*/
    private:
        struct MyStruct;
}
```

user.h

```
class user{
    public:
        /*....methods.....*/
}
```

programmer.h

```
class programmer{
    public:
        /*....methods.....*/
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you aim to achieve?

Comment: @HenningKoehler Implementing an ADT approach for user and programmer. Most important is keeping interal structure of data private to implementation.

Comment: Ah. Your comment clears everything up. You should add that to the question. Currently my downvote is locked in and I can't remove it without an edit. You are looking for the [Pimpl Idiom](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

implementation.h

```
#include <memory>
class implementation{
  public:
    /*....methods.....*/
  private:
    struct MyStruct;
    std::unique_ptr<MyStruct> my_data;
}
```

implementation.cc

```
implementation::MyStruct {
  public:
    /*....methods.....*/
  private:
    ...
};
implementation::implementation() {
  my_data = std::make_unique<MyStruct>();
}
```